# Can you connect two monitors with Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, multiple-monitors, display

I would like to know if you can connect two monitors with Ubuntu, and if you can, then how do you adjust the display settings for the screen resolutions, launcher placement, etc. for multiple monitors?

Comment: Willkommen an AskUbuntu. Diese ist eine englische Webseite, also wär's besser wenn du in Zukunft auf Englisch posten könntest. Danke!
 --- Welcome to AskUbuntu. This is an English site, so it'd be better if you could post in English in future. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can connect 2 monitors with Ubuntu, In display settings, (to be obtained from Displays from System Settings) when you will connect the other monitor, you can enable or disable the option of mirror display depending on the requirement.

Note: The configuration option for additional display will only get enable when the external display is connected, or the PC detects external display